# nginx reverse proxy with WordPress: acb.site.com/wp-admin goes to abc.site.com:port/wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a nginx reverse proxy setup and pointing to an internal server hosting WordPress on port 7002.
The site works fine, however, when I try and access https://abc.site.com/wp-admin I am sent to https://abc.site.com:7002/wp-admin in my browser which fails to load the admin login. I can access https://abc.site.com/wp-login.php and it works fine.

Kinda stumped why this is happening. How can I get https://abc.site.com/wp-admin to correctly come up with the Wordpress login page
?
Below is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name abc.site.com;

    include security.conf;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/chain.pem;
    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        server_name_in_redirect off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout 90;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_buffers 32 4k;
        proxy_pass https://10.1.1.7:7002;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you checked browser cache ? if your browser has cache of this url, it also can do like that.

Comment: The redirect to port 7002 will be coming from `10.1.1.7:7002`. You have `proxy_redirect off;` so you are not attempting to correct it here.

Comment: Thank you, looks like this was the issue. Can’t believe I missed that!